# How to code a simple settable voice counter in html?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I would like to create a simple voice countdown counter that I can set. I would like to listen to the counter so that I do not have to count. Any existing code, or where to start ?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow :) As someone voted down, your question seems a bit lacking. StackOverflow is not a code writing or providing idea service. You're expected to code by yourself first. It's okay if your code doesn't work well. We can help you fix bugs. Please update your question to show what you have done/tried so far in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SpeechSynthesis` API for Text-to-Speech, and then use a interval to accomplish the countdown timer. Like so:

```js
var seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
var countdown1 = document.getElementById("countdown");
var intervalVar;
var start;

function start() {
  start = parseInt(seconds.value);
  countdown1.style.display = "block";
  countdown1.innerHTML = start;
  start++;
  intervalVar = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}

function countdown() {
  start--;
  countdown1.innerHTML = start;
  let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(start);
  speech.rate = 2;
  speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
  if (start == 0) {
    clearInterval(intervalVar);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="seconds" id="seconds"><button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<div style="display:none" id="countdown">

</div>
```

You may need to adjust `speech.rate` to make it faster for bigger numbers.